# python urllib url quote/unquote issue

Tags: python

Now I have a url which is in quote format:
`http%3A%2F%2Fimages.1datatech.cn%2F%E5%A4%A7%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8.png`

I want to unquote it into  a real url, and my condition is:
1, "a real url" should be able to access directly, such as wget xxxxxx
2, "a real url" should only be in ascii. Actually I need to save this into a database entry, and the field is set to be ascii 2000 character, so it is "indexable". A string too long, or a unicode string of 2000 character, will not be indexable.

So I set `b = urllib.parse.unquote(a)`, I got:
`http://images.1datatech.cn/大数据应用.png`

That violate my second rule. So I try to quote it again: `c = urllib.parse.quote(b)`, I got:
`http%3A//images.1datatech.cn/%E5%A4%A7%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8.png`

Question, how can I get
`http://images.1datatech.cn/%E5%A4%A7%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8.png` ?

I don't want to use `c.replace('%3A', ':')` because there might be other characters such as `? & =`   might need special treatment, if I go down this route.

This seems to be a simple task (transfer a quote url to a real url), but I am stuck. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `urllib.parse.quote` with `safe` parameter (for python3):

```
import urllib.parse

url = 'http%3A%2F%2Fimages.1datatech.cn%2F%E5%A4%A7%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8.png'
url = urllib.parse.quote(urllib.parse.unquote(url, encoding='utf-8'), safe=':/')
print(url)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the "safe" option. I checked the official document in https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html , and looks like it is very interesting. How do I know what to use for `safe`?  How about other signs like `? & =` ?

Comment: By default, safe using '/', so I think for your instance, using '/:' for safe characters is reasonable. And if the URL contains characters like '?&=', you need also add them into the safe. By default only [A-Za-z0-9._-] will not be encoded.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have to use `safe=':/?&='` to get other similar links to work.

Comment: @BenL Even more generally than `safe=':/?&='`, how about `safe=string.punctuation`? (`import string` first.)

Comment: @Asclepius I can see `punctuation = r"""!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_(tilda){|}~"""`  It is very comprehensive, but I am not sure about using it. `#` sign should be added into my list  `':/?&=#'` , but others are not supposed to be a sign in HTML link, afaik.

Comment: @BenL Right. On the other hand, I am more inclined to follow a simpler solution due to Occam's razor until I actually find prominent failing examples. In this case, the simpler solution is to not define the subset of punctuation characters that are relevant. I considered this complex URL which didn't fail with my tooling when I used `safe=string.punctuation`: `https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=louth&sll=53.800651,-4.064941&sspn=33.219383,38.803711&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Louth,+United+Kingdom&ll=53.370272,-0.004034&spn=0.064883,0.075788&z=14`